# How to make 2D OpenGL rendering efficient in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I am working on a little project in C++ using OpenGL. I want to be able to render multiple 2D rectangles either in some color or with texture as efficiently as possible.

However, I am doing this in modern C++, so I am writing many wrappers over OpenGL API so that I have better logical structure, RAII, ...

In this spirit I wanted to create a class Rectangle, which would have a method draw() and this method would activate corresponding OpenGL context and call glDrawArrays(). This works fine, but then I realized, that if I wanted to render more rectangles, I would have to cycle through many instances. They would each switch context and I don't think this is an effective solution.

After a bit of thinking my solution was to create a Renderer object, which would hold a single VAO for all Rectangles, associated program, and huge buffer in which I would hold all coordinates for my objects (Rectangle instance would then be like a smarter pointer to this buffer) and then draw them all at once. Of course it would add me a lot of work with managing the buffer itself (adding/removing rectangles). Would it be better?

Also, do you have any tips what else should I focus on?

Comment: You'll very likely benefit from having a look at Data Oriented Programming techniques. They're all about data batching and handling cases where OOP doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you want to minimize the number of drawing calls. Placing a lot of geometry data in a single buffer object and batching it all up into a single `glDraw…` call is definitely the way to go. The best way to go about this is to not think things drawn using OpenGL being individual objects (there is no spoon) but just patches of colour, which by happenstance appear to be rectangles, boxes, spheres, spoons…

A way to implement this using C++ idioms is to have a buffer object class, which internally manages chunks of data contained inside a buffer object. Keep in mind that buffer objects by themself are pretty much formless, and only by using them as a source for vertex attributes they get meaning. Then your individual rectangles would each allocate from such a buffer object instance; the instance in return could deliver the rectangle attributes' indices relative to a certain internal offset (what's passed to `glVertexAttribPointer`); it actually kind of makes sense to have a *buffer object* class, a *object attribute view* class (which manages the attribute pointers) and the actual geometry classes which operate on attribute views.

In preparation of the actual drawing call the geometry instances would just emit the instances of their respective vertices; concatenate them up and use that for a `glDrawElements` call.

Answer (score 0):

If your geometry is not changing then best way is to create VAO with one VBO for geometry of renctangle, one vbo with transformations for multiple rectangles you may draw and one vbo for texture coordinates  and do instancing you remove lot of trafic from cpu to gpu by this.Also try to cache uniforms and dont set their value every rendering call if the values are not changing. Try to use tool like gltrace and see if you can reduce unnecessary state changes. Collect as much data as possible and then only do rendering call.